# Unable to change value of select when setting value in react

Tags: reactjs

Using react, if I set a `value` on a select element, I cant seem to change the select's value. I have seen many threads and examples of doing what I am doing and the examples have been working so not sure what I am doing wrong here.

I am coming into this form as an edit form so I have preexisting data from an API. The particular example I am working with is setting the default value to 'Negotiation'. If I attempt to change the select, it always outputs 'Negotiation' and wont let me change it.

I am using Next.js if that makes any difference. Below is some some simplified code.

```js
export default function OpportunityForm(props) {
  const [opportunity, setOpportunity] = useState<any>(null);
  const [stage, setStage] = useState('_none');

  useEffect(() => {
    // Editing an opportunity.
    if (props.opportunity) {
      setOpportunity(props.opportunity);
      setStage(props.opportunity.attributes.field_stage);
    }
  }, [props]);

  return (
    <>
      <Form.Root>
        <div>
          <Form.Field name='stage'>
            <Form.Label>Stage</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control asChild>
              <select
                id='stage'
                name='stage'
                value={stage}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  // e.target.value is always whatever is set in value.
                  setStage(e.target.value);
                }}
              >
                <option value='_none'>- None -</option>
                <option value='Needs Analysis'>Needs Analysis</option>
                <option value='Negotiation'>Negotiation</option>
                <option value='Proposal'>Proposal</option>
                <option value='Qualification'>Qualification</option>
                <option value='Closed Won'>Closed Won</option>
                <option value='Closed Lost'>Closed Lost</option>
              </select>
            </Form.Control>
          </Form.Field>
        </div>
      </Form.Root>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the selected value index onChange.

```
onChange={(e) => {
              console.log(e.target.selectedIndex);
              // e.target.value is always whatever is set in value.
              setStage(e.target.value);
            }}
```

and can you try to get value by index

```
onChange={(e) => {
              setStage(e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value);
            }}
```

Comment: unfortunately `selectedIndex` doesn't change either. In my case it is always firing 2 for Negotiation.